# Best questions and answers from the 4th quarter of 2021

Tags: discussion, best-of

As I have mentioned in [previous similar posts](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), some Stack Exchange sites, such as [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10763/89356), [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) and [Spanish Language SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta), have (or had, as the case may be) a tradition of trying to identify the best questions and answers from the last quarter. These are contributions that may be posted on a blog or a Twitter account if the site has one; otherwise they are a nice collection of the best contributions made in a community.

In addition to identifying material that can be used to promote the site elsewhere, such a list of nominations can also be used to highlight high-quality contributions that did not get a lot of votes when they were posted.

So what are the rules?

- Find **great questions and great answers** from the last quarter. There are [397 questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-09-01..2021-12-31+is%3Aq) and [625 answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-09-01..2021-12-31+is%3Aa) to choose from.
- You can nominate multiple posts per answer.
- Some sort of explanation *why* the nominated post is particularly good would be worth adding. This can give future contributors an idea of how to write up good questions or answers.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great idea.

I would like to propose :

- An answer of [Is it possible to say "soixante-vingt" instead of "quatre-vingt" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/48385/28591) which explain in multiple context
- The question [Concordance des temps](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/48919/28591) because, even with too quick title, can be fine to explain a concept that is difficult (and not only for no-native french speakers)
- An answer of [Proper Middle French c. 1450 pronunciation for the "Le Roy Engloys" song](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/48723/28591) with sound mention and so much more explaination ! (And not by *jlliagre* which is everywhere and author of lot of good answer)

Comment: I find it.... strange, to say the least,  to make a choice according to post's author.  Shouldn't any  depend on the quality of the post? Since there's only one answer to the question, *Proper Middle French c. 1450 pronunciation for the "Le Roy Engloys" song* the mention "by jlliagre" obviously concerns "Is it possible to say "soixante-vingt" instead of "quatre-vingt" ? " There are two answers to this question, @jlliagre's (+5), the other answer (-1) that you want to promote is not really accurate and far less documented.

Comment: I didn't make the choice according to author, it's just a remark. I don't understand, I mention all answer with more upvote for their question

Comment: @Elikill58 I concur with None. The question about the *Concordance des temps* isn't very clear and technically unanswered. On the other hand, *Le Roy Engloys* one is certainly my favorite for that quarter.